# Replace WooCommerce product short description by selected variation description

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

Can I hide woocommerce short description if variable product description is visible?

Then if I reset the variation, then short description will display again and then hide the variable product description again.

Any help?

Comment: In practice, do you want to display either the short description of the variable product (if no option has been selected) or the short description of the chosen variation (and thus hide the short description of the variable product)? Quite right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace variable product short description by the selected variation description if it's not empty, you can use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'variable_product_jquery_script' );
function variable_product_jquery_script() {
    ?>
    <style>.woocommerce-variation-description {display:none !important}</style>
    <script>
    (function($) {
        var selector  = '.woocommerce-product-details__short-description',
            form      = $('form.cart'),
            shortDesc = $(selector).html();

        form.on('show_variation', function(event, data){
            var varDesc = data.variation_description;       
            $(selector).html( varDesc ? varDesc : shortDesc );
        });

        form.on('hide_variation', function(){
            $(selector).html(shortDesc);
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: If I'm honest, I removed my question because the answer is literally there. Just change ```'.woocommerce-product-details__short-description'``` to ```'.woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description'``` and you're done. This worked for me, but if people are using different description class then it may differ slightly. Please upvote my first ever Java success! Haha.

Comment: @LionHeart-Nerd Sorry, i didn't wanted to threaten you in any way, but is better to ask a new question instead of asking in a comment something different that the original thread. Maybe you could please clean some unnecessary comments, keeping the 4th one that is useful for others, thank you. You are right to don't up vote for useless threads.